# How to force the submitted tasks to utilize all the available cpu cores

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

i am working on a computer with 8 cores.i am trying to parallelize the execution of piece of code. As shown below is how i setup the pool and the specifications of the worker processes.
the problem i have is, when i run the code, the cpu monitor in windows show that none of the cpus "the 7 cores" reachs the peak as shown in the image.
please let me know how to configure the pool and modify the code so that the execution utiluzes the 7 cores

**dissection**:

`self.segmentsContainer` is composed of 7 or 8 segements where each segment is composed of large number of rows

`totalNumOfTasksSegments` as the name implies, it is the number of rows each segment carries

`run` is the parallelized method. is does the following, it receives each segment in `self.segmentsContainer`, process it and return 28 lists

**code**:

```
NUM_OF_TASKS_SEGMENTS = cpu_count() - 1
with Pool(processes=GridCellsPool.NUM_OF_TASKS_SEGMENTS) as pool:
    for res in pool.map(self.run,self.segmentsContainer,chunksize=self.totalNumOfTasksSegments):
        mapResCnt+=1
        self.NDVIsPer10mX10mList.append(res[0])
        self.areasOfCoveragePerList.append(res[1])
        self.interceptionList.append(res[2])
        self.fourCornersInEPSG25832List.append(res[3])
```

**image**:

[image]

Comment: Since my assumption about `chunksize=` was wrong, that just seems to show that your program can't fully utilize a single core. What does `self.run` do?

Comment: @AKX please have a look at my question again i adapt it.would you please tell why do you think that my code can not utilize a single core?what would ne the culprit for that

Comment: Well, you're still not telling us exactly what `self.run` does. But the reason for not being able to utilize a single core is inefficient code, IO-bound code, etc. If you want, you can of course increase the process count _over_ the number of actual cores you have, and see if you get better actual performance by having multiple processes compete over a single core.

Comment: can you please tell me, how can i  increase the process count over the number of actual cores i have,?

Comment: Well, `NUM_OF_TASKS_SEGMENTS = cpu_count() * 2` for instance.

Comment: I'm not an operating system developer or anything like that, but I think I wouldn't want to use an OS that allowed one program to consume 100% of the CPU's resources.  Perhaps the goal that is stated here is unattainable.

Comment: @PaulCornelius The OS will of course schedule all tasks to run as well as it can and not let one process hog everything. Full 100% consumption of all cores is totally possible and attainable, though.